# Read arabic text from db and store in parquet format in s3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

I haver a pyspark script which reads mysql data which contains column values in a data frame and stores the data in parquet format in aws s3 but while querying using aws athena it is showing some random text and not arabic. I am doing something wrong . Please help in getting this sorted.
Text im getting is Ãâ¦ÃÂ±ÃÆÃÂ²..., how this can be converted to arabic .

While reading data from mysql using pyspark i am getting data in format: 'Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø±Ù‚ÙŠØ©'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's an enconding problem. Are your files in S3 in utf8 ?

Comment: @Steven yes files are in utf-8 format. Is there some thing needs to be done while converting dataframe to parquet or while fetching data from mysql using sql_context.

Comment: @Steven or is there any any special property need to be added while creating tables in athena? I just checked columns are being stored in right encoding.

Comment: @Steven i am getting this test while reading from athena 'Ø±Ø§Ø¡ Ø¨Ø§Ù„Ø¯'

Comment: what is the type of your column? is should be nvarchar not varchar

Comment: @bat7 type of column in Athena or mysql? In athena it is string with below properties
``
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'separatorChar'=',') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
``

Comment: I meant in mySql

Comment: @bat7 its varchar in mysql. Is there an way i can handle it in pyspark script to because when i am reading data in pyspark it is showing data in arabic.

Comment: try use nvarchar in mysql instead of varchar, for me it worked!

Comment: @bat7 is there no way without changing the datatype in mysql table?

Comment: this is what worked for me

Comment: @Steven I changed the content-type and encoding to utf-8 in s3 file and still same issue. Files are stored in parquet format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading from mysql we need to pass "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8" with the url string e.g

```
user_df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
                                   url="jdbc:mysql://HOST/DB_NAME?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8",
                                   driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                                   dbtable="users",
                                   user="root",
                                   password="root"
                                  ).load()
```

This resolved my issue.